# Attach JSON to an existing form

Tags: javascript, json, forms, exif

I'm pulling out exif data from a selected image in a blog post form for my personal site. 
I'd like to send along the exif data found as a field of my form formatted as JSON. I'm not sure the correct approach to this. My first thought was to just make a text_area input and set the value of the JSON into that field. Though I feel there has to be a better way.

Thoughts?

Comment: Hello, how are you extracting the exif data from the image?

Comment: This lovely lib 
https://github.com/mattiasw/ExifReader. 

Also, I'm only uploading the image in question client-side to S3 so the image never goes to my server otherwise I would have just done all this server-side.

Comment: You could add a `document.addEventListener('submit', ...` prevent the reload of the page, that is the default behavior of submit `e.preventDefault()`, build a data object with the information of the fields and the data information of the image, build an HTTP request, and fetch with POST sending the data structure that you created, in JSON.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Hey!, Hoy did you do it at the end?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, add the image meta data as a field on data object and send it:

```
// The elements are being instanced outside the event listener. In the event listener we can get the current value of the element
const nameInput = document.getElementById('name') 
const lastNameInput = document.getElementById('last-name')
const idInput = document.getElementById('id')

// A regular button, not a submit one
const sendBtn = document.getElementById("send-btn")

// The event that will listen the button, take the data of your fields and send it in JSON format
sendBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    // The URL of your server
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/users'

    const data = { 
        name: nameInput.value,
        lastName: lastNameInput.value,
        id: idInput.value
    }

    const request = new Request(
        url,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, // If the headers are not defined, your backend application doesn't recognize the data sent with JSON
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }
    )

    try {
        const response = await fetch( request )
        const jsonResponse = await response.json()
        // With the response of the server you have infinite posibilities.
        console.log(jsonResponse)
    } catch (e){
        alert('Error connecting with the server')
    }    
})
```